# reading or open STL file on processing

Tags: processing, windows-7-x64, stl-format

I am using `processing` for Serial Communication and want to read/open the STL file in it, I have STL file in my Harddisk.

Can you please guide me on How do I do fixed it?

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/9703/import-3d-image-in-processing

Comment: @KevinWorkman If you can give a look on coding and do some suggestions according to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read and practically test [this link](https://github.com/technicolorenvy/Processing-Libraries/blob/master/toxiclibscore/examples/mesh/STLImportTest/STLImportTest.pde) from `github`, it is really very useful and best thing is that it is working.

So in your case

1. Just make a directory with any name
2. Put `Below Coding` and actual image file in same folder

I edited it according to your file name so just copy/paste this code followed by all above instruction

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.geom.mesh.*;

import toxi.processing.*;

TriangleMesh mesh;
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;

void setup() {
  size(600,600,P3D);
  mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
  //mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("mesh-flipped.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH).flipYAxis();
  gfx=new ToxiclibsSupport(this);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  lights();
  translate(width/2,height/2,0);
  rotateX(mouseY*0.01);
  rotateY(mouseX*0.01);
  gfx.origin(new Vec3D(),200);
  noStroke();
  gfx.mesh(mesh,false,10);
}
```